# Error in importing sidekit in python on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, libsvm, sidekit

I'm tyring to use *sidekit* toolkit for speaker recognition and I have installed *libsvm* for Ubuntu, I'm using anaconda 3.5. When I try to import *sidekit* I get following import error

```
>>> import sidekit
>>> import theano
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/shivam/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/__init__.py", 
line 141, in <module>
from sidekit.libsvm import *
File "/home/shivam/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/libsvm/__init__.py", 
line 37, in <module>
from sidekit.libsvm.svm import *
File "/home/shivam/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/libsvm/svm.py", 
line 324, in <module>
fillprototype(libsvm.svm_get_sv_indices, None, [POINTER(svm_model), POINTER(c_int)])
File "/home/shivam/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/home/shivam/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/lib/libsvm.so.3: undefined symbol: svm_get_sv_indices
```

Comment: do you have file `/usr/lib/libsvm.so.3` ? Or maybe Python needs different version of `libsvm`.

Comment: I have  this file /usr/lib/libsvm.so.2 which I have installed using `conda install -c conda-forge libsvm=3.21`

Comment: Python needs `usr/lib/libsvm.so.3` but I don't know what difference - maybe it is different version ot it was compillerd with different C/C++ compiler.

Comment: O maybe conda installed correct library but in different folder. Maybe use command `find` to find all `libsvm.so` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installed Sidekit some months ago.

1: If you want to use Sidekit for systems that do not involve SVMs (gmm-ubm, i-vectors etc.), then you can avoid the problem by editing `__init__.py` to not import libsvm. In your case, it is located here: 
`/home/shivam/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/__init__.py`.
Add `libsvm_loaded = False` on line 140 (right above `if libsvm_loaded:`), and libsvm will not be imported.

2: If you want to be able to make SVM-based systems (such as in the example script `rsr2015_svm_gmm.py`), the Sidekit [documentation](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/sidekit/libsvm.html) tells you to (after libsvm installation) copy `libsvm.so.2` into `.../python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/libsvm/`.

If `import sidekit` still gives the same error, check line 125 of `.../python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/__init__.py` and make sure it says `libsvm = CDLL(os.path.join(dirname, 'libsvm.so.2'))`

Note that `__init__.py` and will be replaced if you are to update Sidekit.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this exact same error when trying to import sidekit.  I tried installing every libsvm package I could find (both Python and apt-get), but the only way I could fix this error was to download and compile libsvm from source.  Its not as bad as it sounds - its a tiny library, it seems - only took 5 seconds to compile.

Assuming you have git installed (apt-get install git-core), the total set of commands I used were:

```
cd ~/ && \
git clone https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm.git && \
cd libsvm && \
make && \
cd python && \
make && \
cp ~/libsvm/libsvm.so.2 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sidekit/libsvm/ && \
rm -rf ~/libsvm
```

**Note:** I realise that your error mentions libsvm.so.**3** - mine did too, but using libsvm.so.**2** worked for me...so that seems to be the only file that contains svm_get_sv_indices!