# Error in importing sidekit with theano on ubuntu

Tags: python, installation, theano-cuda, sidekit

I had installed using conda and the terminal is giving me an error about GPU but I am not using a GPU.

---

```
>>> import theano
>>> import numpy
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import sidekit
```

And this throws the following error:

```
Import theano

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:

 https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/adit/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from sidekit.libsvm import *

File "/home/adit/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/libsvm/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from sidekit.libsvm.svm import *

File "/home/adit/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/libsvm/svm.py", line 324, in <module>
    fillprototype(libsvm.svm_get_sv_indices, None, [POINTER(svm_model), POINTER(c_int)])

File "/home/adit/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)

File "/home/adit/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/lib/libsvm.so.3: undefined symbol: svm_get_sv_indices
```

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://askubuntu.com OR  http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The Theano warning is not the reason of why you can't import Sidekit though.

Sidekit will not be imported because it cannot locate the libsvm library file, which Sidekit requires you to install manually.
Check out the [Sidekit guide](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/sidekit/libsvm.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050356/error-in-importing-sidekit-in-python-on-ubuntu) question for a solution.